# Exercice in c pointer in matrice

Tags: c

I tried to make i program that creates a default numbers on matrice with pointer but don't get result, without any errors. Could someone help me? I'm using "Dev C" as IDE.  ...........................................................................................................................................

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <Math.h>
    typedef struct S_Matrice
    {
            int L;
            int C;
            int * mat ;
            }Matrice;
            //creation du matrice
    Matrice *CreerMatrice(int l, int c)
    {
    Matrice *m ;
    m = (Matrice *)malloc(sizeof(Matrice)) ;
    m->L = l ;
    m->C = c ;
    m->mat = (int *)malloc(l * c* sizeof(int)) ;
      return m;
    }
    //remplir une matrice
    Matrice *remplirMat(int l, int c)
    {
    Matrice *m ;
    m->mat = (int *)malloc(l * c* sizeof(int)) ; 
    m->L = l ;
    m->C = c ;
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i < l;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j <c; j++)
            m->mat=(int *)(rand()%26 + 'a');
        }
        return m;
     }
     void afficher(Matrice *m, int l, int c) {
      int i, j;
    m->L = l ;
    m->C = c ;
      for (i = 0; i < m->L; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m->L; j++)
          printf("%d ",m);
        printf("\n");
      }
    }

    int main() {
      int c = 8;
      int l = 8;
       Matrice *mat= CreerMatrice(c,l);
      remplirMat(8,8);
      afficher(mat,8,8);
      printf("bravo");
      getch();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with a variable named `l`. It is easily mistyped/mispelled as the digit `1` and such a typo easily goes undetected.

Comment: In `remplir`: you do `Matrice *m;  m->mat=...` but `m` has no memory allocated!

Comment: In `remplir`: you do `m->mat=(int *)(rand()%26 + 'a');` but this overwrites the memory allocated to `mat`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *remplirMat* you have

```
Matrice *m ;
m->mat = (int *)malloc(l * c* sizeof(int)) ;
```

you do `m->mat` while *m* is not initialized

A `m = (Matrice *)malloc(sizeof(Matrice));` is missing

After that :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 11972616 
bravo
```

All the times the same values, because of the line in *remplirMat*

```
m->mat=(int *)(rand()%26 + 'a');
```

you forget the indexes *i* and *j* to store into the allocated array saved in *m->mat*, probably must be :

```
m->mat[i*c +j]=(rand()%26 + 'a');
```

After you do not write well the matrix in *afficher*

```
printf("%d ",m);
```

try to write the allocated array address, you need to write the elements :

```
printf("%d ",m->mat[i*c +j]);
```

but that write only 0 ... because in *main* :

```
  remplirMat(8,8);
```

and the filled matrix is lost, must be

```
  mat=remplirMat(8,8);
```

and in fact `Matrice *mat= CreerMatrice(c,l);` is useless because the allocated matrix is lost. Probably *remplirMat* must get the matrix in argument rather than to allocate a new one

so better to replace :

```
Matrice *remplirMat(int l, int c)
{
  Matrice *m ;
  m = (Matrice *)malloc(sizeof(Matrice)) ;
  ...
  return m;
}
```

by

```
void remplirMat(Matrice *m, int l, int c)
{
   ...
}
```

and of course in *main* replace

```
 Matrice *mat= CreerMatrice(c,l);
 mat=remplirMat(8,8);
```

by
     Matrice *mat= CreerMatrice(c,l);

```
 remplirMat(mat, 8,8);
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra ma.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
110 119 108 114 98 98 109 113 
98 104 99 100 97 114 122 111 
119 107 107 121 104 105 100 100 
113 115 99 100 120 114 106 109 
111 119 102 114 120 115 106 121 
98 108 100 98 101 102 115 97 
114 99 98 121 110 101 99 100 
121 103 103 120 120 112 107 108 
bravo
```

I encourage you to add a *FreeMatrice* to free the allocated resources

```
void FreeMatrice(Matrice *m)
{
  free(m->mat);
  free(m);
}
```

and to call it in *main*, after that :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra ma.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
==12798== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12798== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12798== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12798== Command: ./a.out
==12798== 
110 119 108 114 98 98 109 113 
98 104 99 100 97 114 122 111 
119 107 107 121 104 105 100 100 
113 115 99 100 120 114 106 109 
111 119 102 114 120 115 106 121 
98 108 100 98 101 102 115 97 
114 99 98 121 110 101 99 100 
121 103 103 120 120 112 107 108 
bravo
==12798== 
==12798== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12798==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12798==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,316 bytes allocated
==12798== 
==12798== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12798== 
==12798== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12798== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I had several cases where I lost modification when entering / editing an answer during a long time, so I prefer to do by step ^^

Comment: for(i=0; i < ligne; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < colonne; j++)
        m->t[i*ligne + j] = (rand()%26 + 'a');
    }

Plz could you explain this loop.. how this table t is uploading??

Comment: @YounesMed you allocate doing `malloc(l * c* sizeof(int))` so all the elements are put in an array of dimension 1. It is needed to decide where to put the elements into, one classical way is to put all the elements of the first line, when of the second lines etc, this is what `i*c + j` does because there are _c_ element per line and _i_ is the line number (from 0) and _j_ the column number (from 0 too). Warning `i*ligne + j` is wrong if _ligne_ is the number of lines

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!  note that the function `remplirMat` returns a matrix structure which is being lost because you do not capture the return value.

Because you have the actual data in an integer array, you need to insert into that array the line `m->mat=(int *)(rand()%26 + 'a');` constantly redefine what `m->mat` is.  It looks like you are attempting to make a two dimensional array to hold the matrix data, so to insert into the matrix, I would do something like:

```
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i < m->L, i++)     // assuming m->L is the number of rows
    for(j=0; j< m->C, j++)        // assuming m-C is the number of columns
        m[i*(m->L) + j] = (rand()%26 + 'a');
```

OK, so what is going on here?

1. The line `m->mat = (int *)malloc(l * c* sizeof(int)) ;` is allocating enough memory to hold l*c integers, in effect `m->mat` is an integer array.  Now how you store the data of the matrix into your array is totally up to you, you just need to be consistent.  From the looks of you code you are storing the data in row-major form, *i.e.* you place the elements for the first row into the array and then the second row.
2. the term `i*(m->L) + j` is an idiomatic way of converting an index in the form of (row, column) into a single index.  For example, if I have a 4x4 array, I need to figure out where the element at say A(3,4) (the element in the third row and forth column) can be found in the one-dimensional array that you've created.  We use the formula `row*MAX_ROWS + col`

Consider the following conversion (assuming a nested loop like you are using) where the variable row is your variable `i`, and the variable col is you variable 'j'.  MAX_ROWS is set to 4

```
element         linear index    row      col        row*MAX_ROWS + col   
A(1,1)             0             0        0           0*4 + 0 = 0
A(1,2)             1             0        1           0*4 + 1 = 2
A(1,3)             2             0        2           0*4 + 2 = 2
A(1,4)             3             0        3           0*4 + 3 = 4
A(2,1)             4             1        0           1*4 + 0 = 4
```

Thus you can see how the mapping from row, column to a single index works.

Given all of this, I would modify you program as follows (I also got rid of the one character variable names), I've combined the functionality of CreerMatrice and remplierMat into a single function.  I also had to remove getch(), as it is a Windows only API and I did my testing on a Linux box.

```
typedef struct S_Matrice
{
        int rows;
        int cols;
        int * mat ;
} Matrice;

//creation du matrice
Matrice *CreerMatrice(int rows, int cols )
{
    Matrice *m ;
    int ndx,jdx;

    m = (Matrice *)malloc(sizeof(Matrice)) ;
    m->rows = rows ;
    m->cols = cols ;
    m->mat = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int)) ;


    for(ndx=0; ndx < rows; ndx++)
    {
        for(jdx=0; jdx < cols; jdx++)
        m->mat[ndx*rows + jdx] = (rand()%26 + 'a');
    }

    return m;
 }

void afficher(Matrice *m) 
{
  int ndx, jdx;
  for (ndx = 0; ndx < m->rows; ndx++) 
  {
      for (jdx = 0; jdx < m->cols; jdx++)
          printf("%d ", m->mat[ndx*n->rows + jdx]);
      printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() 
{
    int c = 8;
    int l = 8;
    Matrice *mat= CreerMatrice(c,l);
    afficher(mat);
    printf("bravo");
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles on ubuntu using gcc 5.4.0 with the command line `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall` and produce the output:

```
110 119 108 114 98 98 109 113 
98 104 99 100 97 114 122 111 
119 107 107 121 104 105 100 100 
113 115 99 100 120 114 106 109 
111 119 102 114 120 115 106 121 
98 108 100 98 101 102 115 97 
114 99 98 121 110 101 99 100 
121 103 103 120 120 112 107 108 
bravo
```

Comment: Thanxs for your help, it's working properly now!!

Comment: for(i=0; i < ligne; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < colonne; j++)
        m->t[i*ligne + j] = (rand()%26 + 'a');
    }

Plz could you explain this loop.. how this table t is uploading??

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in `remplirMat`. It should be:

```
Matrice *remplirMat(int l, int c)
{
    Matrice *m= malloc(sizeof(Matrice));
    m->mat = (int *)malloc(l * c* sizeof(int)); 
    m->L = l;
    m->C = c;
    for(int i=0; i < l;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j <c; j++)
            m->mat + (i*m->C) + j= (int)(rand()%26 + 'a');
    }
    return m;
 }
```

First, memory had to be allocated to `m`. Next, you want to set `m->mat[i][j]` to a random letter. But because the compiler does not know how large the rows and columns are, you must do the address calculation yourself: the address is `mat` plus the number of rows (`i*m->C`), plus the current column, `j`.

Comment: this is not the alone problem ^^

Comment: for(i=0; i < ligne; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < colonne; j++)
        m->t[i*ligne + j] = (rand()%26 + 'a');
    }

    return m;      this loop is still not clear for me, plz help